# how to write two text in one line with<li> tag with equal space between them CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to put two text in one line with equal space between those texts. I used `<li>` tag and span inside of it. However, it did not look like as I wanted. Here is my code:  I want to display it like so:

[image]

```css
.product-detail-feature ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.product-detail-feature span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 24px;
  padding-right: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-detail-feature">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Malzeme Tipi</strong><span> İroka Ağacı</span></li>
    <li><strong>Üçlü Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 200 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>İkili Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 185 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Tekli Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 175 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Sehpa Ölçüsü</strong><span> 75 x 80 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Renk Seçenekleri</strong><span> 
       <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span> </span>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Kumaş Tipi</strong><span> Özel Üretim</span></li>
    <li><strong>Özel Üretim</strong><span> 3 Haftada Teslim</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
.product-detail-feature ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 360px;
  float: left;
}
.product-detail-feature li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.product-detail-feature li strong {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.product-detail-feature li span:not(.dot) {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
span.dot {
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/osmgv8kt/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS-Tables

```css
.product-detail-feature ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.product-detail-feature ul li {
  display: table-row;
}

.product-detail-feature span {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-detail-feature">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Malzeme Tipi</strong><span> İroka Ağacı</span></li>
    <li><strong>Üçlü Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 200 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>İkili Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 185 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Tekli Koltuk Ölçüsü</strong><span> 175 x 150 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Sehpa Ölçüsü</strong><span> 75 x 80 x 75 cm</span></li>
    <li><strong>Renk Seçenekleri</strong><span> 
   <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span> </span>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Kumaş Tipi</strong><span> Özel Üretim</span></li>
    <li><strong>Özel Üretim</strong><span> 3 Haftada Teslim</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```